# Lower time complexity of two for loop and optimize this to become 1 for loop

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to optimize this loop. Its time complexity is *n*<sup>2</sup>. I want something like *n* or log(*n*).

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j <= n; j++) {
            if (a[i] != a[j] && a[a[i]] == a[a[j]]) {
                x = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The `a[i]` satisfy `1 <= a[i] <= n`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What kind of help do you want? You already know what to do, so just go and do it. Also, this is rather underspecified; without knowing the details of the data, it's hard to even suggest any improvements here.

Comment: I don't know how to optimize this

Comment: Why don't you explain what the code does?

Comment: I have to run this program in 1 sec and n=100000 and its exceeds 1 second limit and i don't know how to optimize my code.

Comment: @perreal: The code executes `x=1` if and only if there exist two elements in a[1…n] whose values are different but are indices of two elements with the same value.

Comment: Think about what the `if` condition is saying. You need to find two element values in the array and use those values as indices to the array. If the values at the new indices are equal and the indices are not, then assign 1 to `x`. This can easily be done in linear time. Draw an array out on a piece of paper and think about it.

Comment: Yes @EricPostpischil you got it right this is exactly what the code is doing. Now, Please help me optimize it.

Comment: @MikeBorklandI am new to coding I know only this approach I have tried two or three things too but it didn't work. If you know how to solve this problem in 1 sec please help.

Comment: @MikeBorkland: Are you assuming all the elements of the array have values in [1, n]?

Comment: @ArjunGupta: There are probably additional specifications  for the problem that you have not stated, such as limits on what the values in the array may be. If so, you should edit the question to include the full specification.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil  Of course. You would have to make that assumption or there would be a segmentation fault.

Comment: @MikeBorkland: No, you do not. The array could be larger than [1…n].

Comment: 1≤N≤10^5,
1≤Ai≤N for each valid i,
the sum of N overall test cases does not exceed 2⋅10^5, these are the limits

Comment: @ArjunGupta: You should edit the question to include the full specification of the problem.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil  True. Either way, as you said, more information would need to be given.

Comment: @ArjunGupta: In part, the code seeks to find two elements in the array that have the same value. If you want to process the array in one pass, think about how you can know if you have seen a value previously or not. If only values 1…n are allowed to be in the array, how can you make a record of which values you have seen or not seen?

Comment: the array has values in [1,n] I will give you 1 case to understand the problem. E.g. : - a[] ={1 1 2 3} in this case n=4 and (a[1]=1)!=(a[3]=2) but (a[a[1]]=a[1]=1) == (a[a[3]]=a[2]=1){ x=1 break; } break the loop and display some  msg "YES";

Comment: @Arjun Gupta  Yes, so think about how you would know when you got to the 1 at index 1 that you had already seen a 1 at index 0. How would you keep track of what numbers you had already seen?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: This question presents a non-trivial algorithmic question. Asking “What have you tried so far?” is inappropriate as it is not a code-crafting question. Finding new algorithms (new to the student, not necessarily new to humanity) may require finding a different way to think about a problem; it is not something that one can expect will be solved by trying to write code.

Comment: The only close votes are for “unclear what you are asking” or “too broad.” Neither is appropriate. The problem posed by this question is clear and specific.

Comment: Answering the _problem_ is trivial. Answering it in a way that will actually help the OP, given the complete lack of information about their level of knowledge, is not.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I will try :

Let us call B the image by a[], i.e. the set {a[i]}: B = {b[k]; k = 1..K, such that i exists, a[i] = b[k]}

For each b[k] value, k = 1..K, determine the set Ck = {i; a[i] = b[k]}.
Determinate of B and the Ck could be done in linear time.

Then let us examine the sets Ck one by one.
If Card(Ck} = 1 : k++
If Card(Ck) > 1 : if two elements of Ck are elements of B, then x = 1 ; else k++

I will use a table (`std::vector<bool>`) to memorize if an element of 1..N belongs to B or not.

I hope not having made a mistake. No time to write a programme just now. I could do it later on, but I guess you will be able to do it easily.

Note: I discovered after sending this answer that @Mike Borkland proposed something similar already in a comment...

Comment: is set represents loop?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question. Set here represents a mathematical set. For example, you could use a std::vector<int<int>> to represents the Ck sets. One single loop (O(N) operations) could determine them. Take a pen and try to do the exercise by hand on a little example. I process often like that.

Answer (score 1):

Since sometimes you need to see a solution to learn, I'm providing you with a small function that does the job you want. I hope it helps.

```
#define MIN 1
#define MAX 100000 // 10^5

int seek (int *arr, int arr_size)
{   

    if(arr_size > MAX || arr_size < MIN || MIN < 1)
            return 0;

    unsigned char seen[arr_size];
    unsigned char indices[arr_size];

    memset(seen, 0, arr_size);
    memset(indices, 0, arr_size);

    for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
    {   
            if (arr[i] <= MAX && arr[i] >= MIN && !indices[arr[i]] && seen[arr[arr[i]]])
                    return 1;
            else
            {   
                    seen[arr[arr[i]]] = 1;
                    indices[arr[i]] = 1;
            }   
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Ok, how and why this works? First, let's take a look at the problem the one the original algorithm is trying to solve; they say half of the solution is a well-stated problem. The problem is to find if in a given integer array *A* of size *n* whose elements are bound between one and *n* ([1,*n*]) there exist two elements in *A*, *x* and *y* such that *x* != *y* and *Ax* = *Ay* (the array at the index *x* and *y*, respectively). Furthermore, we are seeking for an algorithm with *good* time complexity so that for *n* = 10000 the implementation runs within one second.

To begin with, let's start analyzing the problem. In the worst case scenario, the array needs to be completely scanned at least one time to decide if such pair of elements exist within the array. So, we can't do better than *O*(*n*). But, how would you do that? One possible way is to scan the array and record if a given index has appeared, this can be done in another array *B* (of size *n*); likewise, record if a given number that corresponds to *A* at the index of the scanned element has appeared, this can also be done in another array *C*. If while scanning the current element of the array has not appeared as an index and it has appeared as an element, then return yes. I have to say that this is a "classical trick" of using hash-table-like data structures.

The original tasks were: i) to reduce the time complexity (from *O*(*n*^2)), and ii) to make sure the implementation runs within a second for an array of size 10000. The proposed algorithm runs in *O*(*n*) time and space complexity. I tested with random arrays and it seems the implementation does its job much faster than required.

Edit: My original answer wasn't very useful, thanks for pointing that out. After checking the comments, I figured the code could help a bit.

Edit 2: I also added the explanation on how it works so it might be useful. I hope it helps :)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I can't think of anything @Jorge Lopez I would like to see your solution. Please help me.

Comment: This isn't an answer, not even a hint. I'd delete it!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21339740)

Comment: @EricPostpischil, enzo, you are right. I edited the answer, perhaps I should have done this from the first time :)

Comment: @ArjunGupta, I edited the answer so you can check a small implementation

Comment: @iod I guess you are right. For now I edited the answer so it provides some help.

Comment: @EricPostpischil right, that'd be better. I changed that. Thanks!

Comment: `memset(seen, 0, arr_size);` should be `memset(seen, 0, arr_size * sizeof *seen);`, and similar for the other `memset`.

Comment: Thanks, it solves my problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil well, as the array is declared in stack we know that the size is going to be always `arr_size`, since otherwise the program won't be loaded, and that the size of unsigned char is 1 we can safely get away with just `arr_size`. Plus, I wouldn't like to add more complexity so that the code is close to an algorithm :)

Comment: @TobySpeight You're right, I have been updating my answer quite a lot. In fact before I asked the author of the question if he wanted to see an implementation as  many people like EricPostpischil gave him very nice pedagogical idea of the algorithm. Anyhow, perhaps this will help other people so I took your criticism into account and added some explanation.

Comment: Well, @ArjunGupta, I'm glad it helps. I added some explanation and perhaps it'll help some more. You can also consider making the answer as useful ;)

Comment: It's much better with the explanation - have a +1!

Answer (score -1):

> I want to optimize this loop. Its time complexity is n<sup>2</sup>. I want something like *n* or *log(n)*.

Well, the easiest thing is to sort the array first. That's *O(n log(n))*, and then a linear scan looking for two adjacent elements is also *O(n)*, so the dominant complexity is unchanged at *O(n log(n))*.

You know how to use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), right? And you know the complexity is *O(n log(n))*?

And you can figure out how to call [`std::adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find), and you can see that the complexity must be linear?

---

The best possible complexity is linear time. This only allows us to make a constant number of linear traversals of the array. That means, if we need some lookup to determine for each element, whether we saw that value before - it needs to be constant time.

Do you know any data structures with constant time insertion and lookups? If so, can you write a simple one-pass loop?

<sub>Hint: [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) is the general solution for constant-time membership tests, and Damien's suggestion of [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is potentially more efficient for your particular case.</sub>